# How can I make an Android consume a SSL service API in local network?

Tags: android, api, ssl

We have an Android app that needs to consume an API only through https from a local computer. If the android device is outside the local network, everything works fine (we have ssl over a domain), but if the router does not know to resolve correctly the domain, the android cannot access the API, from the local network.

What can I do to make this work?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: What code do you currently have in place? is there any reason the API HAS to use ssl locally and cant just use  http when accessing localhost?

Comment: How are you getting SSL certificates for your server? SSL certificates are tied to a domain name, which in turn is tied to a public IP address. The local network presumably has a private IP address.

Comment: I have an ssl aquired for mydomain, it is installed on the server, the router has the redirect to the server, all works ok from outside my lan. Can I make it work in lan? That's my problem.